# Dask SQLAlchemy query fails in Docker workers: Exception: cannot pickle 'weakref' object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have a Dask distributed application running workers on Docker containers. Problem is that when I run an SQLAlchemy read_sql_query statement, I get an exception in the workers saying **Exception: cannot pickle 'weakref' object**

Note: this runs fine with local workers, only fails with Docker.

This is the reduced code:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class test_loans(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'test_loans'
  loan_id = Column(String)
  fico_score = Column(Integer)
  __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint('fico_score'),)

t = aliased(test_loans)
stmt2 = select([ t.loan_id,t.fico_score])
ddf = dd.read_sql_query(stmt2, con=db_str, index_col='fico_score', npartitions=20)
ddf.compute() # <----- fails here when the statement is triggered in the workers
```

And this is the exception:

```
2022-08-15 20:37:26,984 - distributed.protocol.pickle - INFO - Failed to serialize (<function apply at 0x7fcfee313160>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x7fcfbc7115e0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select object at 0x7fcf6edc5430>, 'mariadb://user:xxxxx@host.docker.internal:3306/bank_0001', Empty DataFrame
Columns: [loan_id]
Index: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'fico_score']])). Exception: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
2022-08-15 20:37:26,987 - distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 109, in dumps
    frames[0] = msgpack.dumps(msg, default=_encode_default, use_bin_type=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msgpack/__init__.py", line 38, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 294, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 300, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 297, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 264, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 231, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "msgpack/_packer.pyx", line 285, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer._pack
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 100, in _encode_default
    frames.extend(create_serialized_sub_frames(obj))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 60, in create_serialized_sub_frames
    sub_header, sub_frames = serialize_and_split(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 444, in serialize_and_split
    header, frames = serialize(x, serializers, on_error, context)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 266, in serialize
    return serialize(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 316, in serialize
    headers_frames = [
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 317, in <listcomp>
    serialize(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 366, in serialize
    raise TypeError(msg, str(x)[:10000])
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type tuple', "(<function apply at 0x7fcfee313160>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x7fcfbc7115e0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select object at 0x7fcf6edc5430>, 'mariadb://xxxx:yyyy@host.docker.internal:3306/bank_0001', Empty DataFrame\nColumns: [loan_id]\nIndex: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'fico_score']]))")
2022-08-15 20:37:26,989 - distributed.comm.utils - INFO - Unserializable Message: [{'op': 'update-graph-hlg', 'hlg': {'layers': [{'__module__': 'dask.highlevelgraph', '__name__': 'MaterializedLayer', 'state': {'dsk': {"('from-delayed-45f566e88ca4c6d12a8197c6d219b27b', 2)": <Serialize: ('read_sql_chunk-from-delayed-45f566e88ca4c6d12a8197c6d219b27b', 2)>, "('from-delayed-45f566e88ca4c6d12a8197c6d219b27b', 8)": <Serialize: ('read_sql_chunk-from-delayed-45f566e88ca4c6d12a8197c6d219b27b', 8)>, "('from-delayed-45f566e88ca4c6d12a8197c6d219b27b', 5)": <Serialize: ('read_sql_chunk-from-delayed-45f566e88ca4c6d12a8197c6d219b27b', 5)>, "('read_sql_chunk-from-delayed-45f566e88ca4c6d12a8197c6d219b27b', 2)": <Serialize: (subgraph_callable-8219b5cb-9a04-436c-ad29-d643f53e22d3, (<function apply at 0x7fcfee313160>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x7fcfbc7115e0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select object at 0x7fcf6edc5430>, 'mariadb://xxxx:yyyy@host.docker.internal:3306/bank_0001', Empty DataFrame
Columns: [loan_id]
Index: []], (<class 'dict'>, [['engine_kwargs', (<class 'dict'>, [])], ['index_col', 'fico_score']])))>, "('from-delayed-45f566e88ca4c6d12a8197c6d219b27b', 1)": <Serialize: ('read_sql_chunk-from-delayed-45f566e88ca4c6d12a8197c6d219b27b', 1)>, "('read_sql_chunk-from-delayed-45f566e88ca4c6d12a8197c6d219b27b', 5)": <Serialize: (subgraph_callable-8219b5cb-9a04-436c-ad29-d643f53e22d3, (<function apply at 0x7fcfee313160>, <function _read_sql_chunk at 0x7fcfbc7115e0>, [<sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select object at 0x7fcf6edc5bb0>, 'mariadb://xxxx:yyyy@host.docker.internal:3306/bank_0001', Empty DataFrame
```

Is this a defect or I'm doing something wrong?

Package versions:

```
dask                         2022.8.0
dask-glm                     0.2.0
dask-ml                      2022.5.27
dask-xgboost                 0.2.0
distributed                  2022.8.0
SQLAlchemy                   1.4.40
cloudpickle                  2.1.0
```

Comment: By local workers, you mean LocalCluster, but with processes, or something else? Please supply your versions of dask, distributed, sqlalchemy and any other package you think might be involved, for your host and docker systems.

Comment: Also, what is `Base` here - is this ORM?

Comment: Added the `Base` declaration and the versions. By local workers I mean the default workers when Dask is initiated in a local environment.

Comment: ah, so you mean the threaded scheduler, without distributed at all? That's a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for dask.dataframe.read_sql_query says that the first argument `sql` must be:

> ```
> sql : SQLAlchemy Selectable
>    SQL query to be executed. TextClause is not supported
> ```

However, you have passed an ORM-based query. It may not be apparent that sqlalchemy has both ORM and SQL-statement based APIs, but you can only use the latter for the reason that you have found: ORM session classes are not serialisable. They contain references to open sessions and cached state.

The fact that this worked for you with the default threaded scheduler is an accident: with threads, objects do not need serialisation, and are simply passed by reference; and pandas doesn't care whether you use the ORM or SQL-statement API. Dask-distributed does care, and this is unrelated to docker, LocalCluster would fail too).

An appropriate SQL-statement selectable looks like

```
from sqlalchemy import sql
sel = sql.select([sql.column("number"), sql.column("name")]).select_from(
        sql.table("test")
    )
```

(this taken from the tests - adapt to your query)

You can also create tables that know about their columns and have some automatic linking of stuff with this API, but it may be a bit of a learning experience for you.

Final note: if you simply want to `.compute()` the results, load it into memory, then you will not gain anything by using dask over using pandas. I assume you eventually want to process the partitions in parallel, and this was just for example.

Comment: It worked fine. To answer your note, you are right, the intent is to run a SQL statement, load the partitions and process them in parallel with workers in Docker containers. This is done because the result of the SQL statement retrieves millions of rows.